# Form Clear/Submit Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I have a HTML form, I need to clear the form inputs when a key is pressed and default content gets deleted as well. If reset is clicked, the form resets to its default "Enter ect" and you have to input something again. Also, if submit is clicked without one of the fields entered, it should display an error saying one of my fields are empty, how would I do that using JS?

I tried using JS to clear the default form but all of them get deleted at once rather than the one that gets clicked on.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title> Forms </title>
  <style>
    span {
      padding-left: 10px;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      width: 20%;
    }
    button { margin-left: 10px; }
    body {
      width: 80%; margin: auto; font-family: sans-serif;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="prototype.js"></script>
  <script src="formsubmit.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1> Task 2: Keyboard  Events and Form Submit </h1>
  <p> <span>Name:</span> <input id="input1" value="Enter Name" name="Name"></p>
  <p> <span>Id:</span> <input id="input2" value="Enter ID" name="ID"></p>
  <p> <span>Email:</span> <input id="input3" value="Enter Email" name="Email"></p>
  <p>
  <button id="submitButton" type="button"> Submit </button>
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
  </p>
  <p style="color:red" id="ErrorMessage"> &nbsp; </p>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
window.onload=function(){

  document.getElementById('input1').value = "";
  document.getElementById('input2').value = "";
  document.getElementById('input3').value = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title> Forms </title>
  <script>
  //window.onload = Reset();
  function reset(){
  document.getElementById('input1').value = "";
  document.getElementById('input2').value = "";
  document.getElementById('input3').value = "";
  document.getElementById('ErrorMessage').innerHTML = "";
}

function submit(){
  var inp1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  var inp2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  var inp3 = document.getElementById('input3').value;
  if(inp1 == "" || inp2 == "" || inp3 == "")
  {  
  document.getElementById('ErrorMessage').innerHTML = "Please enter all fields";
  }
  else{
  //do your code here
  document.getElementById('ErrorMessage').innerHTML = "";
  }
}
  </script>
  <style>
    span {
      padding-left: 10px;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      width: 20%;
    }
    button { margin-left: 10px; }
    body {
      width: 80%; margin: auto; font-family: sans-serif;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="prototype.js"></script>
  <script src="formsubmit.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1> Task 2: Keyboard  Events and Form Submit </h1>
  <p> <span>Name:</span> <input id="input1" value="" placeholder="Enter Name" name="Name"></p>
  <p> <span>Id:</span> <input id="input2" value=""
  placeholder="Enter ID" name="ID"></p>
  <p> <span>Email:</span> <input id="input3" value="" placeholder="Enter Email" name="Email"></p>
  <p>
  <button id="submitButton" type="button"  onclick="submit()"> Submit </button>
  <button id="resetButton" type="button"  onclick="reset()"> Reset </button>
  </p>
  <p style="color:red" id="ErrorMessage"> </p>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if I were to have a form `<form id="myForm" action="http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/~mbrown/EECS1012/testForm.php" method="get">` in it, how would i make it so if I try submitting and one field is empty, the information doesnt get submitted and gives me the enter all fields message because I added a form and if I leave in field empty, the information still gets sent without showing **please enter all fields** option

Comment: you have to do code with in if else condition otherwise it will not works

Comment: how would I go doing that?

Comment: if(inp1 == "" || inp2 == "" || inp3 == "")
  {    }
  else{
  //do your code here
  }

Comment: so how would i use this form link with <form id="myForm" action="http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/~mbrown/EECS1012/testForm.php" method="get"> in JS so I get the same error if I submit it without entering all 3 fields? I tried giving it a name and creating a new function but still didnt work

Comment: can you add your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ and give me jsfiddle link, I will be solve